COW Pages in Fork() System call after child process aborts for generating a core dump
I am trying to generate core dump of a running process by forking the process and aborting the child so that the child will generate a core dump(essentially giving me a dump of the parent's VM), however i wanted to do this with minimum interruption in the parent process. Linux uses COW in fork so all the pages in the parent's VM are marked read only and will incur page faults whenever a write operation is done in the parent after this fork and abort which leads to a lot of overhead.

Is there a way to minimize this overhead by reducing the page faults since the child will only read the memory to produce a core dump therefore marking read only is not really necessary.
Is there any other way to produce a core dump of a running process without crashing it besides this, gcore provided by linux causes a lot of interruption to the process for generating a core dump is there anything faster ?

Forking and aborting is faster than using gcore to produce a core dump. Is there a cleaner and faster way to get a core dump of a running process with minimum interruption.
